# In a flutter app I'm using doOnData from rxdart how do I remove it?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a flutter app, a widget is issue a `doOnData(doIt).listen(null)` on an observable that is global to the app. If the widget is disposed, I start getting errors. How can I remove the `doIt` from the observable during the widget's `dispose` method?

Comment: Why don’t you use a hot observable (broadcast)? If it’s global to the app I’m assuming it will be subscribed multiple times with different consumers so that might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, you start listening to the stream (or *Observable* in rxdart) and want to stop listening on widget dispose. *listen* method returns you an instance of `StreamSubscription` that you can cancel at any time using *cancel()* method. It's also possible to pause a subscription.